# C++ Split Wide Char String

Tags: c++, split

I'm trying to split a WideChar String in to an array, Here is the way I'm doing this :<>

```
WCHAR* Message = _T("This is a sample text"):
wchar_t *pwc;
CStringArray Command;
pwc = wcstok(Message, L" ");
int Count = 0;
while (pwc != NULL) {
    pwc = wcstok(NULL, L" ");
    Command.Add(pwc);
    Count++;
}

for (int i = 0 ; i <= Count ; i++)
{
    AfxMessageBox(Command[i]);
}
```

The problem is I do not have "This" in my final result array
Whats wrong ?

Comment: Where's the array? You're just printing tokens.

Comment: Works for me (once I've fixed up the code to compile in a Linux environment, but that's wcstok() taking a third parameter to allow reentrancy, shouldn't change the behaviour. You are talking of an "array", which makes me think you are perhaps doing something wrong in your copying of the elements out of the string?

Comment: I'm adding tokens to CStringArray (CStringArray::Add)

Comment: I have edited the question and changed the code to what Im currently using

Comment: If you'd run the code you originally showed us you'd have seen it working - which might have helped you work out why this version doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the call to `Command.Add` before the assignment to `pwc` in the loop - as it stands you're moving on to the second token before doing your first `Add`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, Do I need to `delete pwc;` when I finished my work ?

Comment: No. (It'll be null by then anyway.) You don't `new` anything, so there's nothing to `delete`.

Answer (score 1):

I am having no issues with your source. All string components are printing perfectly.

Here's my full working code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <wchar.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t wcs[] = L"This is a sample string";
    wchar_t *pwc;
    pwc = wcstok(wcs, L" ");
    while (pwc != NULL) {
        wprintf(L"%ls\n", pwc);
        pwc = wcstok(NULL, L" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: That would be better as a comment - it doesn't really answer the question. (Thanks for not using `_T` though!)

Comment: I agree, but I have little reputation here ;)

Comment: Here, free reputation.